# IF statement not working in RHEL 6 (workd in RHEL 5)

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement, rhel

I have a simple if statement that works fine in RHEL 5, but for some inexplicable reason, fails in RHEL 6:

```
if [[ ! $1 =~ "(one|two|three)" ]] ; then
    echo -e "\n***Invalid number"
    usage
    exit 1
else
    action=$1
fi
```

I can use a case statement which works fine or re-write it but more than anything, I'm curious as to what has changed, assuming it is the version of RHEL and not something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regex **must not not be quoted in newer BASH** (starting from BASH version 3.2), try this:

```
if [[ ! "$1" =~ (one|two|three) ]] ; then
    echo -e "\n***Invalid number"
    usage
    exit 1
else
    action="$1"
fi
```

To be able to use quoted regex you can use:

```
shopt -s compat31
```

**EDIT:** As glen commented below you can use `!~` operator also i.e.

```
[[ "$1" !~ (one|two|three) ]]
```

Comment: You can use `!~` instead of `! ... =~`

Comment: The best way of keeping the script compatible across the versions is to use a variable `re='(one|two|three)'` and then use `[[ $1 !~ $re ]]`.

Comment: Thanks all ... that's good to know. Although the `!~` didn't seem to work.  I'll have a play with that.

Comment: Wait, d'oh, I missed the quotes around the variable. Face palm.